# How to replace the contents of several lines with "deleted" using the .replaceText() method?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

How to replace the contents of several lines (lines are in different children) with "deleted" using the .replaceText() method?

**Google Docs example:**

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rrcp5iR64tBzArfV8W7rnkL5joKQ5YTtyfO7f5m_wps/

I tried this, but this expression doesn't work.

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
body.replaceText("(?s)\{.*\}", "deleted");
```

**Example data:**

**Input:**

```
... 
{{ 
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum  
lorem ipsum
}}
...
```

**Output:**

```
...
deleted
...
```

Comment: The regex looks fine. It is unclear what "doesn't work" means. Please show the result you get when you run the code. If the result is identical to the input, i.e., nothing changed, show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script? In the current stage, it seems that `replaceText` cannot be used for multiple paragraphs. So, in this sample script, I used `replaceAllText` of Google Docs API.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const replaceText = "deleted"; // This is from your question.

  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const matches = doc.getBody().getText().match(/\{\{[\s\S\w]+?\}\}/g);
  if (!matches || matches.length == 0) return;
  const requests = matches.map(text => ({ replaceAllText: { containsText: { matchCase: false, text }, replaceText } }));
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, doc.getId());
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained. In this sample script, the format is kept even when the text is replaced.

##### From:

[image]

##### To:

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#replacealltextrequest)

Comment: How do I modify this code to be able to make a similar substitution if there is an image between {{ and }}?

Comment: @Александр Помозов About your new question of `How do I modify this code to be able to make a similar substitution if there is an image between {{ and }}?`, I would like to support you. But, in this case, it is different from your question. So, can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142831/how-to-replace-a-document-fragment-which-matches-a-regular-expression-with-de

Comment: @Aleksandr Pomozov About your this comment `Created a new question stackoverflow.com/questions/75142831/…`, you posted this after I posted an answer for your new question. So, I'm worried that you have never seen my answer. How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function lfunko() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText('^.*$','');
}
```

Comment: Yes, it generally works, but it does the wrong job. It removes all text in the document, not the text between {<..>}. And if you change the second argument from "" to "123", it turns out that replaceText() is not executed for the whole document, but for each child element.

Comment: I don't see any of this information about `{<...>}` in your question

Comment: If you expect all of us to follow your link to your spreadsheet you might be surprised how many don't because we don't wish to reveal our email address to you.

Comment: @Cooper your practice of not following links is respected, but I do not think there is a way for a document or spreadsheet owner to discover the identity of people visiting their file, unless they are both in the same Google Workspace domain. The reverse can be done of course — visitors can discover the identity of the owner. Also, script projects do reveal the identity if _edited_. But documents and spreadsheets should be perfectly safe to edit anonymously. Follow-up in [google-fu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu) if you want to explore that further.