# Google Doc Script for Replacing Text Including Line Breaks

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to create a Google Docs script function that will replace all the instances of specific text including line breaks with other text that deletes the line break.

I have a long document that I'll be adding to regularly by coping and pasting from other text (I know, not ideal, but I don't have a way to export raw text) and then cleaning it up. In Google Docs I can do a Find and Replace for M\navatar\nM and replace it with M (With the "Match using regular expressions" checked) and then do another find and replace for J\navatar\nJ and replace with J to help with cleanup. I'd like to add these as functions in a script so I can do all the replacements at once.
[image: image of google doc find and replace setup]

I tried using the replaceText function, but it will not accept the \n expression for the line break and so it finds nothing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: By guessing your question, I proposed a sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my guess for my understood your question. In your current issue of `I tried using the replaceText function, but it will not accept the \n expression for the line break and so it finds nothing.`, I thought that the reason for this issue might be due to that `replaceText` cannot be used for multiple paragraphs. If my understanding is correct, I thought that this sample script might be able to be used. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74819309/7108653) But, from your question, I thought that in this case, reflecting your goal in this sample script might be complicated a little. So, I would like to introduce a sample script for achieving your goal using the sample script as an answer as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document and save the script. Before you use this script, [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  // This is from your question.
  const replaceTexts = [
    { "from": "M\navatar\nM", "to": "M" },
    { "from": "J\navatar\nJ", "to": "J" }
  ];

  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const requests = replaceTexts.map(({ from, to }) => ({ replaceAllText: { containsText: { matchCase: false, text: from }, replaceText: to } }));
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, doc.getId());
}
```

- In the case of `replaceAllText` of Google Docs API, it seems that the multipe paragraphs can be used.

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following sample result is obtained. In this script, the format is kept even when the text is replaced.

##### From:

[image]

##### To:

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#replacealltextrequest)

Comment: Sorry that I didn't include more of what I had tried in my question. I had tried a lot of things, but none that got even close, they would run but nothing would change. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Flash_Dalton Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I had tried a lot of things, but none that got even close, they would run but nothing would change.`, although I'm not sure about your actual Document, in this case, as a common sample, please test my proposed sample input situation in my answer and run the script. By this, I think that my output result can be obtained.

Comment: Yes, @Tanaike, your answer above worked great! It took me a bit to with through it, first I missed the instructions to enable the Docs API, but once I did that everything worked as expected. Your example sample was exactly what I was going for. I marked your answer as correct. Thanks again!