# How to replace a document fragment (which matches a regular expression) with "deleted"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

How can I replace a fragment of a document (which matches a regular expression) with "deleted", provided that within the fragment (for example, between {{ and }}) there can be both plain text and images and other formats of information.

**Input:**

```
... 
{{ 
lorem ipsum
*image*
lorem ipsum
}}
...
```

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIGdo.png)

**Output**:

```
...
deleted
...
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtGPn.png)

**How I tried it** (*this only works with text*)**:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const replaceText = "deleted"; // This is from your question.

  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const matches = doc.getBody().getText().match(/\{\{[\s\S\w]+?\}\}/g);
  if (!matches || matches.length == 0) return;
  const requests = matches.map(text => ({ replaceAllText: { containsText: { matchCase: false, text }, replaceText } }));
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, doc.getId());
}
```

- [The first version of the question is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74812138/how-to-replace-the-contents-of-several-lines-with-deleted-using-the-replacete/74819309)

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

In your situation, when the images are included in the range enclosed by `{{` and `}}`, your showing script cannot be used. Because the texts including the images cannot be replaced with `replaceAllText`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.

In order to achieve your goal, it is required to detect the index of `{{` and `}}`. From your showing sample image, in this answer, it supposes that `{{` and `}}` are the separated paragraphs. Please be careful about this.

When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const replaceText = "deleted"; // This is from your question.

  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const docId = doc.getId();
  const ranges = Docs.Documents.get(docId).body.content.reduce((ob, o) => {
    if (o.paragraph && o.paragraph.elements.length > 0) {
      o.paragraph.elements.forEach(oo => {
        if (oo.textRun && oo.textRun.content) {
          const value = oo.textRun.content.trim();
          if (value == "{{") {
            ob.temp = o;
          } else if (ob.temp && value == "}}") {
            ob.ar.push([ob.temp.startIndex + 2, o.endIndex - 3]);
            ob.temp = null;
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return ob;
  }, { ar: [], temp: null }).ar.reverse();
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
    const requests = ranges.map(([startIndex, endIndex]) => ({ deleteContentRange: { range: { startIndex, endIndex } } }));
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docId);
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().replaceText("{{.*}}", replaceText);
}
```

- When this script is run, first, the index of `{{` and `}}` is retrieved. And, the content ranges between `{{` and `}}` are deleted by Docs API. And also, the replacement text is put.

#### Note:

- **From your showing sample image, in this answer, it supposes that the texts of `{{` and `}}` are the separated paragraphs. Please be careful about this.**

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteContentRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#deletecontentrangerequest)